How to find all connected vertex starting from root, but in the order from most inner one to most outer one?
Let's say I have a data as below:
test_df_4 <- data.frame(inner_obj= c(1, 3, 2, 6, 5),
                        outer_obj = c(3, 4, 1, 7, 6))

I see there two separate objects, one consist of: 1, 2, 3, 4 and second one is: 5, 6, 7. My understanding is that 2 goes into 1, then 1 goes into 3 and finally 3 goes into 4. For the second object it is: 5 goes into 6 and 6 goes into 7. In my case these are code blocks nested in each other, so to compute 4, I need to start from 2, then 1, then 3, then 4. For the second object: I need to start from 5, then 6, then 7.
I would like to get a list with this order - for the first object it should be 2, 1, 3, 4 and for the second: 5, 6, 7.
I know how I could find a starting points (roots):
root <- igraph::degree(igraph::graph_from_data_frame(test_df_4), mode = "in")
  root <- as.integer(names(root)[which(root == 0)])

But I still have a problem what function should I use to get the desired order. I would prefer to use igraph package.
Expected output:
list(c(2, 1, 3, 4),
     c(5, 6, 7))

or something similar, i.e. the order and possibility to differentiate between separate objects / graphs is most important.

What is the exact expected output?

@s_baldur thank you for asking! My quesion is now edited to include expected output.

Is the input graph always a disjoint union of directed path graphs? For the sake of example, suppose your starting graph is g<-make_kautz_graph(2,1). What is your expected output now?

It's good to mention that the description in your title sounds like a breadth-first search. Look this up if you're not familiar with the concept yet, and check out the bfs() function.

You can try ego + diameter like below
g <- test_df_4 %>%
    graph_from_data_frame()
vrt <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0]
ego(g, node = vrt, order = diameter(g), mode = "out")

which gives
> ego(g, node = vrt, order = diameter(g), mode = "out")
[[1]]
+ 4/7 vertices, named, from 009c3ff:
[1] 2 1 3 4

[[2]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from 009c3ff:
[1] 5 6 7


Or, we can use all_simple_paths like below as well
g <- test_df_4 %>%
    graph_from_data_frame()

vrt <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "in") == 0]
vnd <- V(g)[degree(g, mode = "out") == 0]

unlist(lapply(vrt, all_simple_paths, graph = g, to = vnd), FALSE, FALSE)

which gives
[[1]]
+ 4/7 vertices, named, from 4e99e5a:
[1] 2 1 3 4

[[2]]
+ 3/7 vertices, named, from 4e99e5a:
[1] 5 6 7


This is very helpful answer and I just decided to use your solution, because I made some tests also with different data than in my question and see that it works better for my use case.

You can feed the root nodes into igraph::all_simple_paths and select the longest for each root:
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(test_df_4)

result <- lapply(which(degree(g, mode = "in") == 0), function(x) {
  V(g)$name[unname(unlist(tail(all_simple_paths(g, x), 1)))] |>
    as.integer()
}) |> unname()

Which gives
result
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2 1 3 4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 5 6 7


Thank you very much. At first, I couldn't believe your function will work, because I have tried all_simple_paths (but didn't mention this) and after trying again with your code, I see that my mistake was to pass "2" to from parameter in all_simple_paths while I should pass "3". Looks like I don't understand the difference between names and indices in igraph, but I will think about this.

@gss I made the same mistake en route to this answer but quickly realized what the problem was.

The problem is that the vertex with index 2, has name "3". To avoid this use: g <- graph_from_data_frame(test_df_4, vertices=seq(7)).
